# MQTT Publish error on different platforms

Tags: python, c#, mqtt

I have MQTT broker (mosquitto) running on raspberry pi which has a static IP address. When I run the Python script to publish message from another raspberry pi from ouside ,it works. But if I run the same code from PyScripter on windows the connection times out. or even from visual studio C# application which use an MQTT library to send (publish) messages to that broker I receive error while connecting. Is it a platform based error or do i need to also have a mqtt broker running on windows?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the error was due to the firewall restrictions on my windows platform. It worked when i connected my computer to different WLAN network. MQTT broker was not required to be installed on windows.